# ng-click does not work at times

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, tabs

Following is my controller code

```
   app.controller('testCtrlr', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.currentTab = [];

    var tabs = [{
        "ID": $scope.AddedWorkFlowTabs++,
        "Name": "Step " + $scope.StepCount++,
        "Customizations": { QuestionGroups: [] }

    }],

  IsSameNameTab = false,
   selected = null,
   previous = null;
    $scope.tabIndex = 0;

    $scope.tabs = tabs;
    $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
    $scope.onTabChanges = function (tabIndex) {
        //you can add some loading before rendering
        $scope.tabIndex = tabIndex;
        $scope.currentTab = $scope.tabs[tabIndex];
    };

    $scope.addTab = function (title, view) {
        debugger;
        //angular.forEach(tabs, function (tb, key) {
        //    if (tb.Name == title) {
        //        IsSameNameTab = true;
        //        showToastrMessage('error', 'You cannot create a step with same name.!');

        //    }
        //});


        if (!IsSameNameTab) {

            $scope.WorkFlow = {
                "ID": $scope.AddedWorkFlowTabs++,
                "Name": "Step " + $scope.StepCount++,
                "Customizations": { QuestionGroups: [] }

            }

            $scope.tabs.push($scope.WorkFlow);
            $scope.activeTabIndex = ($scope.tabs.length - 1);
            $scope.currentTab = $scope.WorkFlow;
            $scope.tabIndex = $scope.tabs.length - 1;

        }
        IsSameNameTab = false;
    };


    $scope.removeTab = function (index) {
        //var index = $scope.tabs.indexOf(tab);
        $scope.tabs.splice(index, 1);


    };
});
```

and following is my cshtml code

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="testCtrlr">

    <tabset>
        <tab sortable-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-click="onTabChanges($index)" active="activeTabIndex">
            <tab-heading>

                {{tab.Name}}
                <a ng-click="removeTab($index)" ng-href=""><i class='fa fa-2x fa-close' ng-hide="tabs.length==1"></i></a>
            </tab-heading>


        </tab>
        <tab-heading>
            <i class="fa fa-2x fa-plus" ng-click="addTab(tTitle)"></i>
        </tab-heading>

</tabset>
</div>
```

I am using angularjs 1.6.3 and bootstrap 3.0.0 and latest version of angular bootstrap tabs. My issue is that the close icon on the tabs does not work on the active tab at times and the remove Tab method is not called i-e ng-click sometimes does not fire on the active tabs close icon. Please if anyone could tell me what exactly it is, i would be glad. Thanks.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem**, See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks @georgeawg. I minified my code.